# PHP - How to block files access in specific directory from the external

Tags: php, permissions, file-access

I made a very simple dashboard with HTML/PHP/JS (and a MySQL database) where some users (after a secure login with username and password) can access and insert some activities with details and attach a file in PDF format.
My dashboard is in a directory like `/var/www/my-dashboard` and inside there is another directory with all the PDF file uploded by the users: `/var/www/my-dashboard/files` with a structure like this:
`/var/www/my-dashboard/files/file1.pdf`
`/var/www/my-dashboard/files/file2.pdf`
`/var/www/my-dashboard/files/file3.pdf`

The users have to login to the dashboard to insert an activity and upload the PDF file so a non-registered user can't do this. The problem is that a non-registered user with a specific link can access the PDF files from the internet (with a link like this: `http://[IP/DNS]/files/file1.pdf`).
I want to avoid this that these files can only be opened and viewed by the registered user. How can I implement this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use PHP to display the PDFs.**

Make sure to store your PDF files in a folder, which is not accessible via a direct HTTP request.

*Example: Put it into /var/www/pdfs/ and reach the directory via PHP or block access to your specific folder in your Nginx or Apache2 configuration.*

```
$file = 'file1.pdf';
  
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  
@readfile($file);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! Is there a way to do this with the .htaccess configuration?

Comment: Of course. Just like that in your folder with the PDFs should work:

`Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
<Files ~ "\.(pdf)$">
Deny from all
</Files>`

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work :( ... maybe it is not the right syntax?

Comment: Do you use Apache2? If this doesn't work for you, try to add `RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/.+\.(pdf)$` in your Apache2 conf file and restart Apache2! Replace "folder" with your folder name that contains the PDF files in it.

Comment: Yes, in this way it works but unfortunatly it blocks all the request (also the request from the dashboard).... i tried this: 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http?://192.168.1.69/.*\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(folder/.*\.pdf|folder/.*\.jpg|folder/.*\.jpeg|folder/.*\.png)$ - [L,F,NC]          it seems working, but maybe it isnt' the best solution...

Comment: Make sure to load the files with PHP and not via direct access! Just tried it with the Apache2 conf and the PHP code and it worked.

Comment: maybe you misunderstanding my goal: i want to block the direct access at the files (with the IP + folder name + file name, without login), but i want to allow the access for the users from the dashboard

Comment: Try to add a session or cookie check to the code. I created a test page where I recreated what I wrote. Get-Login creates a session, Delete-Login deletes the session, Open-PDF opens test.pdf if you have set a valid session and test.pdf is never openable without PHP and a valid session. https://stackexchange.corsin.io/security/ <- did you mean that?

Comment: Yes it is the solution using the PHP code. I didn't try it yet but i'm sure it works! I was asking mysels if there is the possibility to do the same thing with the .htaccess file and keep the PDF files in the actual position in th work direcotry (with the web site files) because in this way i can add only the .htaccess file, instead with your PHP solution i have to modify enought code.